# Estimate population variance / mean from truncated distribution with known cutoff, but without parametric assumptions

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, truncation

Suppose you have a sample of $N$ iid random variables $X_i$ drawn from an unknown (but finite variance) distribution but with a known upper-cutoff $K$ and therefore support $[0,1,2,...,K]$ but un-truncated would have support $[0,1,2,...\infty]$.

Given your $N$ observations, you're interested in estimating the unknown population mean and variance of the untruncated distribution without making parametric assumptions.  Of course, if you had no truncation this is straightforward and could be estimated with:

$$\bar{X}=\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$$

The answers I've found typically have to do with making a parametric assumption.  Is this critical to do?  Or is there a way to avoid this and just recover a sample mean and variance?

Comment: Set $X_i=K$ if $X_i>K$, then calculate the sample mean and sample variance. BTW, we estimate population variance/mean; we calculate sample variance/mean.

Comment: I don't see how that would give you a consistent estimate of the untruncated population mean

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor - I don't believe there is *any* way to get a consistent estimate given a fixed truncation point w/o making an assumption about the underlying distribution.

Comment: @jbowman, I would post this comment as an answer. Maybe worth noting that the sample mean isn't even guaranteed to be a consistent estimator for *complete* data without some parametric assumptions (e.g. consider a Cauchy ...)